# Filament Cost vs. Quality?

Tags: print-material, material

I'm a 3D printing newbie, and I bought some Hatchbox PLA to start with since it is recommended by the community it seems.

Is there really a steep quality drop off if you go for brands that are 50% less than Hatchbox?  What does that quality drop off look like?

Comment: Not going to answer as im also new - but I "purchased"  a trial of some filament - it was around $45/kg - it seemed to be much more tolerant and required much less calibration - it also did not block as often as the cheaper stuff around $30 a kilo - This does work , and the quality can be tuned - its just more work in setup.  I think the evenness in print is acceptable - but probably not as good as the more expensive sample.  I have run out of the sample so I cant really compare any more

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @TecTec3's answer:

#### Parameters that define filament quality:

- Diameter variance: If there is too much fluctuation in diameter, the filament might get stuck.
- Material Quality: I had really expensive filament that was brittle and did tend to snap when it was extruded. Other filament just didn't melt but started burning up and regulary clogging my extruder.

#### My opinion:

I'd say you shouldn't go with too cheap filament and stick with one that works out best for you. If you have issues try another brand. It's impossible to tell quality just from the price.

Answer (score 0):

There is no massive difference in print quality of PLA filaments unless you start going under 10 dollars US for a 1 kilo spool. The filament that I use is yoyi  PLA that can be found on Amazon for about 20 bucks, this filament works really nice with my printer and it is fairly cheap. Just make sure you never use the hobby king brand PLS as the quality on that truly is horrendous.